# Arm mbed online Compiler error 230 (or -230?)

Tags: compiler-errors, arm, mbed, bbc-microbit

I tried to compile some examples for the microbit with the arm-embed online compiler however no matter what I do I can't get anything compiled. Tried also an empty project, log-out and log-in again, close the browser and open the browser, switch off uBlock etc and still the same error. React on users with the same question but there is no answer.

Possible to solve this in some way?

[image: sitation-compiler-error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are aware of the "error 230" issue with the online compiler and Mbed OS 2 targets such as the Micro:bit, please keep your eye out for a fix.

In the meantime, you can use the [offline Mbed CLI](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-cli/) to compile your code for the Micro:bit, a quick start guide for the Mbed CLI is available here: https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.10/tutorials/quick-start-offline.html

-- Jenny, team Mbed

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. That solution/workaround looks a little complicated, I will wait for the fix. Any idea how long it takes to solve the problem?

Comment: This is easier: https://os.mbed.com/docs/latest/tools/installation-and-setup.html

Comment: I stop to use this tool, really, the bugs are endless. After installing all the countless utilities required and other requirements,  it finally compiles and after a minute it will end with this library error! : *./mbed-os/features/FEATURE_BLE/ble/ArrayView.h:20:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
 #include <algorithm> compilation terminated. * If arm/mbed wants more developers, it must be much easier than this. Takes me hours with no positive result.

Comment: @Codebeat Which target and toolchain are you compiling for?

Comment: Tried verious things and this was the last one: TOOLCHAIN=GCC_ARM
TARGET=NRF51_MICROBIT_B_OTA

Comment: Can you try updating the mbed library to the latest version? In your command line within the project directory do the following:
`cd mbed` then `mbed update`, then try your `mbed compile` command once again in the root project directory

Comment: This is the latest version.

Comment: Which project are you compiling? `microbit-hello-world` or `microbit_blinky`?

Comment: microbit-hello-world

Comment: More info for you: ILETypes.h:24:0,
                 from ./mbed-os/features/FEATURE_BLE/ble/Gap.h:20,
                 from ./mbed-os/features/FEATURE_BLE/ble/ble.h:21,
                 from .\microbit\microbit-dal\nRF51822\nrf51-sdk\source\nordic_s
dk\components\ble\ble_services\ble_dfu\ble_dfu.h:53,
                 from .\microbit\microbit-dal\nRF51822\nrf51-sdk\source\nordic_s
dk\components\ble\ble_services\ble_dfu\ble_dfu.c:33:
./mbed-os/features/FEATURE_BLE/ble/ArrayView.h:20:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
 #include <algorithm> compilation terminated.

Comment: So the `microbit-hello-world` program doesn't use the Mbed 2 library at all and just demonstrates the usage of the micro:bit DAL. I would recommend using the `microbit_blinky` program in order to compile with the Mbed CLI: https://os.mbed.com/teams/BBC/code/microbit_blinky/

Comment: Hi again, I've submitted an issue to the micro:bit DAL repo regarding the compilation errors here: https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-dal/issues/393